# What is Prolog bad at?

Tags: prolog

I was recently trying to learn about Prolog and it seems to map well to a lot of domains, but I was having trouble figuring out what it might be bad at.

So what is it bad at (besides things that need real-time/no-gc performance)?

Comment: Well Prolog is what they call *logical* programming language. So that means usually everything that is *logical* is usually easy (that means you can express it - without much fabrication - as a set of predicates). Things that tend to be more *imparative* are harder in my opinion: things that carry a state. Furthermore one needs special datastructures to have *O(1)* random access.

Comment: Marketing, evidently.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Or maybe too much marketing. Think of the 5th generation craze.

Comment: @false for those who remember that, yeah. For kids taking school today, the week of Prolog amounts to "look at this weird old crap, isn't it awful? aren't you glad you're using Javascript instead?"

Answer (score 9):

I agree with your general assessment that Prolog maps well to **many domains**. In my opinion, even more so than most other languages.

To give one of the few examples where it is bad at:

Prolog is decidedly bad at **number crunching** as it is currently understood. By this I mean many, many largely nonsensical calculations over floating point numbers, accumulating errors in ways that nobody can realistically understand or handle.

This is an area where Prolog implementations **cannot compete** as it is today, since all these calculations incur too much overhead by the way Prolog reasons about terms, and also because the nastiness of these calculations are generally abhorred in the logic programming community, where the focus is rather on **correctness** and **convienence** for users, and other number formats such as **rational numbers** are typically chosen if at all possible.

**However**, and I think that will become an important development of the future, once the extreme shortcomings of floating point numbers have become sufficiently widely understood and better formats (example: **Unums** etc.) have become sufficiently widely known and available, Prolog may become an increasingly important tool also in this area.

In his book, [**The End of Error**](https://www.crcpress.com/The-End-of-Error-Unum-Computing/Gustafson/p/book/9781482239867), John Gustafson gives a beautiful analogy I often think about:

Many decades ago, it took 30 seconds to print a page. When printers become better, it still took 30 seconds to print a page. We did not spend all advancements of technology to print 5000 low-quality pages in 30 seconds, but rather improved the **quality** of the pages thousands of times.

I think number crunching will eventually go in the same direction: Use the increasingly available computing power to improve the **quality** of results, not the quantity.

Comment: Although Prolog may not be good at number crunching, I don't think this shortfall is inherent in the structure of the Prolog language. Prolog is, after all, quite good at "reasoning over integers" with the CLP(FD) library. It's only a library away from having other good number handing capabilities. But one must define what subdomain of number crunching we're talking about.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with everything you said!

Comment: In particular the Ubox approach in part2..., that really is so close to what Prolog IV did.

Comment: Do unums have hardware support like ieee-754? Or does it matter?

Comment: It matters, but it does not matter as much as *correctness* and guarantees that are provided by Unums. Getting a wrong result as fast as possible is generally not as useful as getting a correct result somehow. I have no doubt that hardware implementations of superior number formats will become available in due time, and there are currently already some startups involved in the design and fabrication of such chips.